# Apache NIFI: A cluster or a single big server?

Tags: apache-nifi, activemq-artemis

My flow is as below and is a cron job scheduling every 10 minutes:

1. Query data from a database. Every time the query result could contains 200 million records.
2. Use PartitionRecord to group records by a specific field of the above query result.
3. Transfer the group produced by PartitionRecord to a XML. It hard to say how many flowfiles a group contains.
4. Send the XML to ActiveMQ-Artemis.

I will use NIFI to approach the above flow (requested by my customer).

Now I have below computing resources:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS
- CPU: 48 cores
- Memory: 384 GB
- Storage: SSD, enough space.

And There are two options I can think of:

1. Build a NIFI cluster composing of three nodes. Each node has 16 cores and 128GB RAM.
2. Build a single NIFI with 48 cores and 384GB RAM.

Which options of NIFI platform should I use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pros and cons I can think of:

Single node pros:

- Easier to configure/setup
- Easier to manage

Single node cons:

- Any unexpected issue with the node, you're no longer processing
- Come upgrade time, you may have some downtime
- NiFi may not efficiently use large amounts of RAM (you're not getting as much bang for your buck)

Cluster cons:

- More complex setup/configuration (needs Zookeeper and extra NiFi cluster config)
- More complex management
- Sometimes experiences cluster connection issues

Cluster pros:

- Reasonable level of redundancy
- Should be able to upgrade a node at a time and keep operations going (you would need to investigate how simple this is)
- Should maximize hardware utilization

Comment: Thanks. If not considering all cons issues, only considering the performance, I wonder which option will have better performance for my flow ?